# Why does the 64bit version of a WinForms app sometimes freeze for many seconds

Tags: .net, garbage-collection, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

Since we changed the build of our Windows Forms application to 64 bit and rolled it out, a couple of users are complaining that it feels sluggish and sometimes freezes for up to 10 or even 15 seconds.

Running both 64 bit and 32 bit versions side by side on identical virtual machines on the same host, both take about the same time to start up and they feel similarly responsive - as long as there is enough free RAM. But the 64bit version consumes about 1.5 times (as measured in "private bytes") as much as the 32 bit version.

Now when I decrease the amount free RAM of the virtual machines, the 64 bit version takes much longer to start - which seems to make sense, as with its higher memory consumption it will have to do more GCing, in order to make do with what little memory it got to work with.

The only theory I can come up with is that those freezing customers have too little memory for our 64 bit app to work with, resulting in swapping and/or GCing.

Which would mean

1. they should close other apps or get more RAM
2. we should try to reduce the memory footprint of our app

Or **what other differences between 32 bit and 64 bit could there be, that could make 64 bit freeze?**

There does not seem to be any difference between the 32 bit and 64 bit garbage collectors, apart from the amount of memory they use.

N.B. This app is running on .Net 4.6, using the default GC settings.

Comment: Is there some reason why you switched to a 64-bit build? This is actually the reason why Visual Studio itself is still 32-bit - given how pointer heavy it necessarily is, a 64-bit build will take pretty much double the memory.

Comment: +1 @Luaan Oh the irony: Apparently (I just talked to someone in the know) only to be able to make use of more memory :) Well, that was definitely accomplished. Although I'm not sure if "use" is the right word.

Comment: You can verify whether the freezes are associated with GC by profiling memory and correlating freezes with GC time. You might also watch other performance counters that may relate to your app (always CPU/Memory/Disk, possibly others) to look for resource contention during freezes.

Comment: @EricJ.As soon as I will be able to reproduce the exact issue, I will be able to profile GC, memory and CPU. Up until then, theory is all I have.